Factoring semiprimes via sum of two squares?
The following thoughts came into my head after watching Grant Sanderson's JBPM award lecture here, in which he discusses the fact that we can quickly factor 3599 by noticing it can be written as (60-1)(60+1). This is a nice trick for mental arithmetic, but also can be computed in one's head much faster than checking all of the factors of 3599. It struck me that I don't know the complexity of determining whether a number can be written as the difference of two primes, and I also do not know what percentage of semiprimes can be written as a difference of squares. Apologies if this question is obvious to an expert in the area!
Formally:
Let S be the set of semiprimes, $S = \{ mn : m,n \in Prime\}$, and let D be the set of numbers that can be written as the difference of squares, not counting adjacent squares $D = \{ a^2 - b^2 : a, b\in \mathbb{N} \,,a-b\neq1\}$.
For any number $q \in S$, we have that $q = a^2 - b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$. If $(a-b) \neq 1$ this is a prime factorization.
Finding values for $a^2, b^2$ is sufficient to find the prime factorization of q.
From this observation, we have that factoring any number $q \in S \cap D$ reduces to the problem of finding the squares whose difference is $q$.
I don't know much about this area of number theory, and so my immediate follow up questions are:

Is there a fast algorithm for determining whether a number can be written as the difference of two squares (besides the a-b case). I know the time complexity of factoring is exponential in input length, what do we know about difference of two squares?

What is the density of $D$ within $S$?


I'm thinking that if there is some better-than-exponential algorithm, and a high density for 2), there could be some faster test for factorization that works on a subset of semiprimes.

This does not look like a research-level question. Clearly, a natural number can be written as $a^2-b^2$ with $a-b\ne1$ iff it can be written as a nontrivial product of two integers of the same parity, which holds iff it is either odd composite or divisible by $4$.

You want to read up on the quadratic sieve.
